# Emacs: PageUp PageDown and return to the initial position

Tags: emacs, scroll

In Emacs, why I press PageUp and then PageDown, the cursor does not return to the initial position, but some other place on the page. Is there any way to make it do this? For example, have PageUp and PageDown just move the cursor up or down the number of rows visible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the variable `scroll-preserve-screen-position`.

> A value of t means point keeps its screen position if the scroll
>   command moved it vertically out of the window, e.g. when scrolling
>   by full screens.

Recent versions of Emacs will also preserve the current column even if that column doesn't exist in the intermediate position.

Comment: +1 Ah, glad to see it got into the core Emacs, I'll leave my answer for older (obsolete) Emacsen...

Comment: Thanks nschum. Sorry for the delay. This works pretty well, it still acts a little funny, but much nicer and more predictable than before :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a package you can use to do this: [scroll-in-place](http://www.cs.utah.edu/~eeide/emacs/scroll-in-place.el.gz)

I found it on the [Emacs wiki](http://www.emacswiki.org) page for [SmoothScrolling](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SmoothScrolling).